# VBA - Average cells based on the length of contract

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to average the net value of contracts based on the length of said contract and then place the average next to the corresponding contract length `Column G`.  The values that need averaging are in `Column E`, and their contract length is in `Column D`.  So, for the average value of a contract in that are 3 years will be placed in `G5` and so on.  Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
With Worksheets("Data")
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
   Dim rngNV As Range, Clength As Range
   Set rngNV = .Range("E2", .Range("E2").End(xlDown))
   Set Clength = .Range("D2", .Range("D2").End(xlDown))
   .Range("G2") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 0)
   .Range("G3") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 1)
   .Range("G4") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 2)
   .Range("G5") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 3)
   .Range("G6") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 4)
   .Range("G7") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 5)
   .Range("G8") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 6)
   .Range("G9") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 7)
   .Range("G10") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 8)
   .Range("G11") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 9)
   .Range("G12") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 10)
   .Range("G13") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength = 11)
   .Range("G14") = wf.AverageIf(rngNV, Clength > 11)
End With
```

Comment: Did you try a pivot table?

Comment: So you want VBA code to perform the equivalent of Excel's `AVERAGEIF` function?

Comment: @YowE3K, I believe so, yes, however, contract lengths are not finite and other data has longer data.

Comment: @ScottCraner, Is that something I can perform from VBA?

Comment: Just use `Application.AverageIf` then.  For the last one (I assume you intend to have "More" in F14), just use a condition of `">11"` instead of using the value from column F.  The code should be almost identical to your code for column I, except using `AverageIf` instead of `CountIf`.

Comment: @YowE3K, Added in my code that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel `AVERAGEIF` function takes three parameters:

1. The range to check the criteria against
2. The criteria
3. The range to be averaged

So you need your code to use statements such as

```
.Range("G2") = Application.AverageIf(Clength , 0, rngNV)
```

But your code could be put into a loop to save some coding:

```
With Worksheets("Data")
    Dim rngNV As Range, Clength As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Set rngNV = .Range("E2", .Range("E2").End(xlDown))
    Set Clength = .Range("D2", .Range("D2").End(xlDown))
    For i = 2 To 13
        .Cells(i, "G") = Application.AverageIf(Clength, .Cells(i, "F"), rngNV)
    Next
    .Cells(14, "G") = Application.AverageIf(Clength, ">" & .Cells(13, "F"), rngNV)
End With
```

---

And, if column I is just a `CountIf`, that can be done at the same time:

```
With Worksheets("Data")
    Dim rngNV As Range, Clength As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Set rngNV = .Range("E2", .Range("E2").End(xlDown))
    Set Clength = .Range("D2", .Range("D2").End(xlDown))
    For i = 2 To 13
        .Cells(i, "G") = Application.AverageIf(Clength, .Cells(i, "F"), rngNV)
        .Cells(i, "I") = Application.CountIf(Clength, .Cells(i, "F"))
    Next
    .Cells(14, "G") = Application.AverageIf(Clength, ">" & .Cells(13, "F"), rngNV)
    .Cells(14, "I") = Application.CountIf(Clength, ">" & .Cells(13, "F"))
End With
```

Comment: It works for years 0-6, however I get a `#DIV!/0` message for 7-11.  I am unsure what to fix as it should work.

Comment: @ACohen How is column D calculated?  Are they integral values, or are they just formatted to show zero decimal places?  (`#DIV!/0` would occur if nothing matched the value in column F and, for instance, `7.123` would not match `7`.)  Hmm, but if that were the problem, your column I wouldn't be non-zero.  So how is column I calculated?  Using a `CountIf` or have you used some other method?

Comment: It is an R1C1 equation. So `D2 = (C2 - B2)/365`.  But how would that work perfectly for 0-6?

Comment: @ACohen It undoubtedly hasn't worked perfectly for 0-6, but you probably have a greater sample size in that range and therefore more likelihood of at least some of them being **exactly** 0-6, e.g. exactly 0 days (i.e. 0 years), or exactly 1460 days (1 day short of 4 years).  What values do you want to average to get the value for your `1` for instance?  Is it anything which is `>=1 And <2` or is it `>0 And <=1` or is it `>0.5 And <=1.5`, etc?

Comment: @ACohen And the easiest fix is to use `=INT((C2-B2)/365)`, or `ROUND((C2-B2)/365,0)`, or similar, for cell D2 - but that depends on whether you ever need the exact number for anything else.  (How do you calculate column I?)

Comment: I used Round, and it worked, fine.  Thanks!